# Add configuration when run cache:clear

Tags: symfony, caching

I look for the way to inject more parameters into symfony configuration cache. Currently, I use `kernel.cache_warmer` hook to my class in `services.yml` to generate another yml file in a directory. Then, it will be include in the symfony configuration cache, **are there any possible way to inject a variable into generated config cache without need to create the Yml file?**

Basically, I would like to make cache key changed everytime when run `app/console cache:clear`. Here is my service,

**services.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: version.yml }

services:
    cacheManager:
        class:        "%cacheManager.class%"
        calls:
        - [ setCachePrefix, ["%memcache.deploymentPrefix%"]]

    memcacheDataVersioning:
        class: WarmUpListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.cache_warmer, priority: 0}
```

**WarmUpListener.php**

```
class WarmUpListener implements CacheWarmerInterface{

    public function warmUp($dir)
    {
        $array = ['parameters' => ['memcache.deploymentPrefix' => date('Ymd')]];
        $dumper = new Dumper();
        $yaml = $dumper->dump($array);

        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/version.yml', $yaml);
    }

    public function isOptional()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added to the DependencyInjection/*Extension class as below

***DependencyInjection/somethingExtension.php***

```
$container->setParameter('memcache.deploymentPrefix', date('Ymd') );
```

This will help to inject the variable in the configuration cached without need to make the Yml file and can removed all warmUp hookup on the question.